# Объединить тысячи файлов в один на pyhton

Tags: python

Есть 3354 txt файла и нужно их собрать в один. На просторах нашел код:

```
import glob
 
read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
 
with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Но он совмещает файлы 1 с 10, 10 с 100 и т.д.
Нужно чтобы он совмещал по порядку 1,2,3,4...3354.
Подскажете как это можно сделать?

Если кому нужно:

```
from natsort import natsorted
import glob

filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
sort = natsorted(filenames)
with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in sort:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
             outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте модуль `natsort` для "человеческой" ("натуральной") сортировки. Пример:

```
from natsort import natsorted

read_files = ['1.txt', '10.txt', '2.txt', '11.txt', '3.txt']
for f in natsorted(read_files):
    print(f)
```

Вывод:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
10.txt
11.txt
```

В вашем случае использование может быть такое:

```
for f in natsorted(read_files):
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Прям вот большое человеческое спасибо за либу... Прям вот очень большое